# How to increase the stack size for Titanium Android app

Tags: android, emulation, titanium, appcelerator

I'm using Titanium to build my app, and it works great on the iPhone.  Today is the first time I ran it in the Android Emulator, and it failed miserably.  I dug into the error log, and found this

```
[TRACE] E/TiJSError( 326): (kroll$1: app://app.js) [274,5815] ----- Titanium Javascript Runtime Error -----
[TRACE] E/TiJSError( 326): (kroll$1: app://app.js) [1,5816] - In file:///android_asset/Resources/app/models/base.js:107,0
[TRACE] E/TiJSError( 326): (kroll$1: app://app.js) [2,5818] - Message: Too deep recursion while parsing
[TRACE] E/TiJSError( 326): (kroll$1: app://app.js) [2,5820] - Source: null
[TRACE] E/KrollContext( 326): (kroll$1: app://app.js) [149,5969] Error: null
[TRACE] E/KrollContext( 326): java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I did some research and Don Thorp, one of the Ti guys, answered to a [similar question](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/81661/too-deep-recursion-while-parsing---fix)

> How large are the files you are using.
>   It's the complexity of the source
>   that's the problem, not what the
>   source is doing. This has been
>   addressed in 1.5 and is app
>   configurable via a tiapp.xml setting
>   to up the stack size. Simplification
>   of the source is the best approach,
>   but in some instances, you'll have to
>   up the stack. —

But I haven't found anywhere on how to increase the stack size in tiapp.xml.  Does anyone know the this property?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

After digging into the titanium_mobile source, the TiApplication.java file specifically, I was able to increase the stacksize.  Essentially add this one line to tiapp.xml anywhere between the  root node.  With 32K stack size the app was able to parse all the scripts.

```
<property name="ti.android.threadstacksize" type="int">32768</property>
```